# How to differentiate Encryption from Compression in real time traffic

Tags: encryption, compression, reverse-engineering, data-analysis, raw-data

I work on network traffic filter and I need to classify input IP-traffic into 3 groups:

- Encrypted traffic
- Compressed traffic
- Neither encrypted nor compressed traffic

Compressed and Encrypted data have many similar attributes, such as entropy and character dispersion in content histograms. So it is difficult to distinguish them.

There is a way to classify data when chunk is big (> 1MB), using Chi Square Distribution,   Pi Approximation Error, and Entropy methods. http://www.devttys0.com/2013/06/differentiate-encryption-from-compression-using-math/

This algorithm is not accurate with small amount of data (~1k).

**The question**:

How to differentiate Encryption from Compression in real time traffic (~1k data blocks) with more than 90 percents accuracy?

I know that modern DPI(Deep Packet Inspection) systems already have some of algorithms implemented to deal with this problem.

Do you have some ideas?

Comment: An interesting question, but, unfortunately, too broad for StackOverflow.  Can you narrow down the scope of your question?  About a specific algorithm at least?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark My c++ program analyze incoming IP packets from network card. Then it finds entropy of each packet. If entropy is greater than X percens this is probably encryption or compression. But how can I exactly know what is this (compression or encryption)? Maybe there is another criteria to distinguish compression and encryption? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can't you use protocol metadata/headers?

Comment: @smeso Protocol metadata (Ports) tell me nothing about  encryption or compression. Example:  port 12345. I can`t know data to be encrypted or not. Protocol can be totally compressed,so no headers be visible.

Comment: What I mean is: *the other end* is supposed to be able to decompress/decrypt the data, so there must be *something* that tells it what to do. Or are we talking about an unknown protocol that is fully encrypted or compressed with unknowns algorithms since the beginning?

Comment: @smeso Yes, we are talking about an unknown data stream. If data is encrypted, then just skip it. If data  is 
 compressed then further processing needed

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be to know somehow that there is a limited set of compressed data formats possible. Then you could begin to decode using all of those formats. If one works for some reasonable distance (e.g. a hundred or so bytes), then there is a very high probability that that is an unencrypted compressed stream.

Otherwise well-encrypted data, well-compressed data, and random data are all indistinguishable from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could play with Shannon's [entropy analysis](http://www.forensickb.com/2013/03/file-entropy-explained.html?m=1) to try to devise a heuristic. A compressed file may exhibit a drop in entropy at the dictionary size boundary, and a (well-)encrypted file won't.

There is practically zero chance of distinguishing a compressed encrypted file from an uncompressed encrypted one. A well-implemented encryption will leak zero  information about the plaintext, also not via entropy.

Comment: I have tried to use heuristic methods. I wrote a test program, that cuts a large file on 128 bytes blocks and then calculates an Entropy, Chi-square, Arithmetic mean of single block, and builds gistograms. I made tests on large (1GB) AES-encrypted file and LZMA-compressed file.  Gistograms (Entropy, Chi, Mean)  of compressed and encrypted file are nearly the same (~98% overlapp). So I think this is not possible to use heuristic here. But this article says that this is possible with high accuracy: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/16c6/a5df8185ca12e5d1a280cea23fb55e27f2f1.pdf